# Filtering out based on the first line, then using it to get the data of the second line

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using BASH and I'm trying to filter out a hashed password. This password belong to the user 'user', but the password is located in the following line of the command listed below.

I need to use AWK to filter out the first and second lines, then extract the hashed password from the second line.

I have no idea where to start!

Cheers

Here is an example of what the text file I'm trying to read contains:

```
   user "user"
            password "IIkku2FE3Q/8.0FWxRL0lE" hash2
            console
                member "administrative"
            exit
   user "user1"
            password "kIieE9XarvNxuBum8dO2ek" hash2
            access console ftp 
            console
                member "administrative"
            exit
        exit
   user "admin"
            password "CdsDs3VDuklNg/Yau91HG." hash2
            access console 
            console
                no member "default"
            exit
        exit
```

I should add that the argument "password "IIkku2FE3Q/8.0FWxRL0lE" hash2" is repeated multiple times. I only need to filter out the one associated with the user 'user'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `gnu awk` should do:

```
awk -v RS="user " -F\" '$2=="user" {print $4}' file
IIkku2FE3Q/8.0FWxRL0lE
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm. Thanks Jotne. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v un="user" '{gsub(/"/, "")}
         $1=="user" && $2==un{u=$2;next} u && $1=="password"{print u,$2;exit}' OFS=, pfile
user,IIkku2FE3Q/8.0FWxRL0lE
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, this doesn't seem to be working. I'm using "less file | awk" and I don't seem to be able to extract the hashed password! Thanks.

Comment: With your output in question I get same output as I showed above.

Comment: @Mesopotamia: Check my updated answer. You can supply any `"user"` on command line using `-v un=` option and that will be searched and printed.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. All worked great with Jotne's answer.

Answer (score 1):

**OR try :**

```
$ awk '$2 == usr{getline;print $2;exit}' FS=\" usr="user" file
IIkku2FE3Q/8.0FWxRL0lE
```

**If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS system`, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`**

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
awk 'f&&/password/{print $2;exit}/user/&&$2=="\"user\""{f=1}' file
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I should add that the argument "password "IIkku2FE3Q/8.0FWxRL0lE" hash2" is repeated multiple times. I only need to extract the password associated with "user". I believe what's needed is a AWK statement which carried both the 'user' as a variable and the password itself. Thanks.

Comment: It's almost there. The password displayed however shows that of 'User1' and not 'user'. Thanks.

Comment: @Mesopotamia Try the new solution. I am able to get the correct answer as per your input file.

Comment: Thanks Jaypal. All worked great with Jotne's answer. I really appreciate your help.